# not able run services on HTTPs for my dropwizard project

Tags: https, keystore, dropwizard, keytool

I am trying to enable HTTPs for my dropwizard project. for that I have added following configuration to enable HTTPs

```
 server:
     rootPath: '/api/*'
     applicationConnectors:
          - type: http
            port: 8080
          - type: https
            port: 8443
            keyStorePath: config/keystore.jks
            keyStorePassword: password
            keyStoreType: JKS
            keyStoreProvider:
            trustStorePath:
            trustStorePassword:
            trustStoreType: JKS
            trustStoreProvider:
            keyManagerPassword:
            needClientAuth: false
            wantClientAuth:
            enableCRLDP: false
            enableOCSP: false
            validateCerts: false
            validatePeers: true
            allowRenegotiation: true
```

"keystore.jks" is the key I created using java keytool.
But on server start I see following exception.

```
Suppressed: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Same configuration worked with dropwizard's example application
https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-example

and not with my appplication. I am using centos VM for my application.

I serched but did not find working solution for me.. Or I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

That error message is produced when your keystore password is incorrect.